# Getting mod_rewrite working on OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a OS X 10.6 install working, with Apache and PHP installed.

However, I cannot get mod_rewrite working.  The contents of my httpd.conf is located here: http://pastie.org/828990

Does anyone know what vital thing I'm missing?

Comment: Can you give us any more information on what is/isn't working? Any error messages in the logs, for example?

Comment: Absolutely nothing - I'm getting the index.php, and no evidence that re-writes are even present.

Comment: what is the url you type? what does your hosts file contain? What does your vhost file contain `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to update /etc/apache2/users/[name].conf  where name is your user name on your computer.

If that file doesn't exist, create it. Then update it to allow mod_rewrite rules:

```
<Directory "/Users/[name]/Sites/">
  Options Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: It fixed my Laravel 5.4 routing issue, It was not working, now it is working. Thank you. Actually all I needed was `AllowOverride All`, but thank you for more comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Keith Norman's answer is correct. However, in my case - a cusual home server I use for hobbying/testing - I work directly off the "base" directory of the HTTP server, rather than a `/~user` directory. Consequently, I needed to alter the following line in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
```

Previously it stated:

```
AllowOverride None
```

Answer (score 0):

You need "RewriteEngine = on" somewhere in your config, but 
I can't see it anywhere. This turns on RewriteRule, etc.

Comment: I have this in my .htaccess files

Comment: OK, that's not the problem then. Are you able to show the rewrites that you are trying to do as they aren't in the main config?